# Using For to Call Subs in a Array

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following array, where all the items inside are different subs. Is there any way to do something like this?

```
Dim vetor As Variant
vetor = Array("OcultaProcConv", "AbakVs", "OcultaCSR", "GeraKermas", "Tempos", "OcultaDEP","OcultaAEC", "OcultaEscopia", "OcultaResultados", "MudaNumPag", "OcultaCP", "OcultaCertificado")

For contVetor = LBound(vetor) To UBound(vetor)
    Call vetor(contVetor)
Next contVetor
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this is by using `CallByName`:

```
Dim vetor As Variant
vetor = Array("OcultaProcConv", "AbakVs", "OcultaCSR", "GeraKermas", "Tempos", "OcultaDEP","OcultaAEC", "OcultaEscopia", "OcultaResultados", "MudaNumPag", "OcultaCP", "OcultaCertificado")

For contVetor = LBound(vetor) To UBound(vetor)
    CallByName Me, vetor(contVetor), VbMethod
Next contVetor
```

This assumes the subs are in the same module.

Comment: It also assumes the module is a *class*. `Me` is undefined in a standard module, and we don't know where OP's code is written in.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks for the clarification.  I happened to test this in a worksheet, but you're right, we don't know for sure where OP's code will be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Application.Run` which must be in a `Module` to work. The master macro looks something like this:

```
Sub Dynamic_Call()

Dim Arr: Arr = Array("Test1", "Test2", "Test3")
Dim i As Long

For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
    Application.Run Arr(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

---

Which will call the below subs as per the above Array loop:

```
Sub Test1()
    MsgBox "Test1"
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Test2()
    MsgBox "Test"
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Test3()
    MsgBox "Test3"
End Sub
```